# Invertible matrix of inner product values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ be a basis in inner product space $V.$

I need to prove that the matrix

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
        (v_1,v_1) & (v_1,v_2) & \cdots &(v_1,v_k) \\
        \
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots&\vdots\\ 
        (v_k,v_1) & (v_k,v_2) & \cdots&(v_k,v_k)
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

is invertible.

Any hints?

Comment: I changed {$v_1,v_2,...,v_k$} to $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$. That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> Take a linear combination of the rows which is zero.

**Hint 2**

> So there are coefficients $a_{i}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} (v_{i}, v_{j}) = 0$ for all $j$.

**Hint 3**

> Your aim is to show that all $a_{i}$ are zero.

**Hint 4**

> So for the vector $v = \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} v_{i}$ you have $(v, v_{j}) = 0$ for all $j$.

Comment: Why is the linear combination of the rows is zero?

Comment: You want to prove that **if** a linear combination is zero, then the coefficients have all to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

start with an orthonormal basis $e_i$ of $V$ and create the matrix $W$ where the entries of column $j$ are the elements of $v_j$ in that basis ($w_{ij} = e_i \cdot v_j $ )

Then
$$ W^T W = A  $$

Meanwhile, $W$ is just a change of basis matrix. Is it allowed to be singular?

Your construction is often called the Gram matrix, sometimes Grammian, although I suspect Grammian should refer to the determinant.

See any lattice in [LATTICES](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/). Note that, in order to keep the entries of $W$ integers for an integral lattice, their $W$ may not be square; let's see, the matrix they call BASIS is my $W^T$